# PHP: Adapt number ID to words

Tags: php, html, arrays, converters

What do I need to do to convert the number only if all the number matches?

At the moment, it's converting to each number. (I've tried to do a lot and I didn't succeed)
I would like to know if have any way of adapting to only show the word if the number "is complete", otherwise show the word "Doesn't contain a name record".

Example:
When I try to use the number 1987, the output its: **Name1 Name9 Name8 Name7**, and I want to be only one word: **Name1987**.

```
function numberTowords($num)
{

    $ones = array(
        0 => "Name0",
        1 => "Name1",
        2 => "Name2",
        3 => "Name3",
        4 => "Name4",
        5 => "Name5",
        6 => "Name6",
        7 => "Name7",
        8 => "Name8",
        9 => "Name9",
        10 => "Name10",
        11 => "Name11",
        12 => "Name12",
        13 => "Name13",
        14 => "Name14",
        15 => "Name15",
        16 => "Name16",
        17 => "Name17",
        18 => "Name18",
        19 => "Name19",
        1987 => "Name1987",
        2398 => "Name2398",
    );

    $num = number_format($num, 2, ".", ",");
    $num_arr = explode(".", $num);
    $wholenum = $num_arr[0];
    $decnum = $num_arr[1];
    $whole_arr = array_reverse(explode(",", $wholenum));
    krsort($whole_arr, 1);
    $rettxt = "";
    foreach ($whole_arr as $key => $i) {
        while (substr($i, 0, 1) == "0")
            $i = substr($i, 1, 5);
        if ($i < 20) {
            /* echo "getting:".$i; */
            $rettxt .= $ones[$i];
        } elseif ($i < 100) {
            if (substr($i, 1, 1) != "0") $rettxt .= " " . $ones[substr($i, 1, 1)];
        } else {
            if (substr($i, 0, 1) != "0") $rettxt .= $ones[substr($i, 0, 1)];
            if (substr($i, 2, 1) != "0") $rettxt .= " " . $ones[substr($i, 2, 1)];
        }
        if ($key > 0) {
            $rettxt .= " ";
        }
    }
    if ($decnum > 0) {
        $rettxt .= " and ";
        if ($decnum < 20) {
            $rettxt .= $ones[$decnum];
        } elseif ($decnum < 100) {
            $rettxt .= " " . $ones[substr($decnum, 1, 1)];
        }
    }
    return $rettxt;
}
```

Comment: Please remove the image and replace with text.

Comment: Suggested changes made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> only show the word if the number "is complete", otherwise show the word "Doesn't contain a name record".
> Example: ... number 1987 I want (output) to be only one word: Name1987.

If this is all you need - piece of cake:

```
<!-- this is only a tool for easy test -->
<form><input name="nr"><input type="submit"></form>

<?php
$pattern = array_merge(range(0,19),[1987,2398]);
$nr = $_GET[nr];

echo    in_array($nr,$pattern) ? "Name$nr" : "Doesn't contain a name record";
```

[array_merge()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge) joins arrays, [range()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.range) is kind of array, [in_array()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) checks if a value exists in an array

---

more flexible - for cases you omitted in your question

```
$pattern = [0=>'my name is Zero',
        1=>'I am the ONE',
        12345=>'this is a number',
        '12345'=>'this is a string',
        '7x24'=>'all time shift',
        999=>'almost thousand',
        12=>'call me a dozen'];

echo    array_key_exists($nr,$pattern) ? $pattern[$nr] : "Doesn't contain a name record";

// if you don't like shorthand - different notation:

if(array_key_exists($nr,$pattern)){ echo $pattern[$nr];}
else{   echo "Doesn't contain a name record";}
```

[array_key_exists()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists)

Arrays are fast and nice in use. Built-in functions are optimised and that makes them much better than step-by-step manipulations. Debugging a few lines of code is easy, debugging plenty lines of particular manipulations is a nightmare. For most cases in php the only concern is to find the name of built-in function which do it all at once.

> I didn't want to limit the numbers (...)  want to add more than 200 ids

I didn't limit anything, and it is not that much, even as associative array it wouldn't be big [array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

---

more complex - it's time to organise the code structure

```
function name($x,$arr){
    if(in_array($x,range(130,150))){        $name = 'from 130 to 150';}     //or (($x >= 130) && ($x <= 150)), or ... etc
    else if(in_array($x,range(100,200))){   $name = 'from 100 to 200';}
    else if(array_key_exists($x,$arr)){     $name = $arr[$x];}
    else{                                   $name = 'pass';}
    $z = ($x[0] == 0) ? 'leading zero' : '&lowast;';        //or if-else instead of Elvis, (substr($x,0,1) == 0) ...
    return($z.' '.$name);}

echo    '<p>'.name($nr,$pattern).'</p>';
```

In the `name()` function, sequence is important for the sub-ranges.

[ternary operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) a.k.a. Elvis
[filter_var()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) if you like it

Comment: I didn't want to limit the numbers, because that was just an example, I want to add several different ids (more than 200) to be converted to words. Btw, thanks for the contribution. I'll try to study more, to be able to do this.

Comment: @Toruk if it not what you are looking for - give me at least one example helpful to understand what I am missing, I can't read your mind, please help me to help you ;)

Comment: Thx man, I've adapted your code and I will use it, much easier and cleaner.

Comment: I'm hitting on it and I'm not finding it, can I set it so that from number 130 to number 150 replace it with the same thing?

Comment: Yes, in a many ways - but not all in one line ;) I've updated my answer with some variants